# Change lastwritedate using powershell recursively

Tags: powershell, file, file-attributes

I am trying to change the lastwritedate of all files in a folder and all files in the subfolders using MS Powershell
I got this far to retrieve a list of all files of concern

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse -Filter *.* -File
```

Now I would like to change the date of the found files

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse -Filter *.* -File) | (Get-Item).lastwritetime=$(Get-Date "10/10/2019 01:05 pm")
```

But unfortunately it fails. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok now I found the solution

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse -Filter *.* -File) | foreach {$_.lastwritetime=$(Get-Date "10/10/2019 01:05 pm")}
```

this pipes the output of gci

Comment: BTW, both `-Path .` and `-Filter *.*` are superfluous - those are the defaults anyway, and the expression parenthesis`$()` are not needed either.